# SQL Server 2012 XML Column: How to get the second (2nd) attribute value

Tags: sql-server, xml

We have an XML column that is dynamically generated, which makes the attribute name vary from record to record. In a case, I would like to get the values of the second attribute.

Sample data:

```
ID = 1, ActionXml = <updated ID="8264" BookID="8198" />

ID = 2, ActionXml = <updated ID="8265" PlanetID="8300" />

ID = 3, ActionXml = <updated ID="9780" ParentID="124" />
```

Result I want:

```
ID      ActionID
----------------
1       8198
2       8300
3       124
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do things for you:

```
SELECT  ID, 
        ActionXml.value('(/*/@*)[2]','int') as ActionID
FROM YourTable
```

Output for data above:

```
ID  ActionID
1   8198
2   8300
3   124
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but this will return the value of attribute named "ID". I want to get the value of the 2nd attribute, which we cannot specify by name because it is different per row (BookID, PlanetID, ParentID, etc).

Comment: Oh, sorry, don't get it in a first place :) changed answer, please, check.

Comment: Yep, it worked! just fixed some parenthesis and it did helped save me some hairs:  ActionXml.value('(/inserted/@*)[2]', 'varchar(50)') AS ActionID. Thanks a lot!